# Writing to HBase from multiple processes

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, thread-safety, hbase, hdfs

I have to put around 2.5 Tb of data in HBase DB. Since it will take a long time for a single process to write it to DB, I was trying to create multiple processes to do this. But I am doubtful whether it is safe to do that because I am calling `batch.commit(finalize=True)` from multiple processes simultaneously. I am using `1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129` version of HBase in my system.

I am doing all the write operations through HBase REST API. Because of doing multiple operations I am getting the following errors on my server:

```
2017-08-07 11:01:18,311 INFO  [hconnection-0x5e834655-shared--pool3-t52497] client.AsyncProcess: #7542, table=clueweb12, attempt=12/35 failed=124ops, last exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTooBusyException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTooBusyException: Above memstore limit, regionName=clueweb12,http://www.innovativeusers.org/list/archives/2006/msg058,1502034291085.f923654226ace7491d61f8b67764c46f., server=node9.local,16020,1499079576247, memstoreSize=539000216, blockingMemStoreSize=536870912
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkResources(HRegion.java:3824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.batchMutate(HRegion.java:2977)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.batchMutate(HRegion.java:2928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:167)
 on node9.local,16020,1499079576247, tracking started null, retrying after=20140ms, replay=124ops
```

Is this error leading to loss of information?

Comment: This may not lead to data loss as RegionTooBusy exception will resolve on its own. If you have not disabled WALs then it should be fine. It is possible that the data may show up late, as it will have to reprocess from the recovered edits.